# Jquery validate if/else errorplacement and plus placement in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I have a form where the placement for radiobuttons is different then for the other elements in the form.

I would like to keep this but also add the errors into a div. Is it possible to do this?

Right now i have this for the radiobutton placement

```
$('#newform').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
            error.prependTo( element.parent() );  
        }
        else { // This is the default behavior of the script  
            error.insertAfter( element );
        }  
    },
    rules{XXX},
    messages{}
```

And so on. How  can I add the errormessages to a div without removing the current funcionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>use the errorLabelContainer option :</strike>

```
$("#myform").validate({
   errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
   wrapper: "li"
})
```

this will place all errors in a list (`li`) within a DOM element with an ID of messageBox

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)

Sorry i missunderstood your problem ....

try this :

```
$('#newform').validate({
        onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
                error.prependTo( element.parent() );  
            }
            else { // This is the default behavior of the script  
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }
            error.appendTo('#errordiv');
        },
```

This will keep your current functionallity but also append the message to the div with an id of 'errordiv'

Comment: that doesnt seem to work in combination with the errorplacement. The div with id #messagebox just stays empty.

Comment: @logistef Updated my answer - sorry miss-understood your question

Comment: I have tested it without my code and it doesn't seem to work either :s

Comment: Altough, i didn't check everything. Now i lost my validation next to the labels and radiobuttons. It only shows the messages in the div now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4724/discussion-between-logistef-and-manseuk)

Comment: @logistef there is another option - try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/xTdYr/2/